# Dwarf won't move because of a goblin who's not there

Tags: dwarf-fortress

In my current game of Dwarf Fortress I just had some injuries and deaths due to an ambush.  Now I have a Fisherdwarf who is laying there unconscious and unattended.  Every other tick I get an accouncement saying `Urist McWounded cancels Rest, interrupted by Goblin Maceman`.  However there is no living, free Goblin on the map.  How can I get my dwarf medical attention?

Comment: Have you tried application of magma? Then poor Urist will finally get his rest.

Comment: @JavadocMD I've thought about trying a re-injury with a spike.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this happen to me yesterday.  I channelled out the square underneath him and the downward motion seemed to trigger the correct "Damn I hurt, where's the hospital?" response.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try a spike first, (don't want to dig holes in my lawn), but I'll try this too.

Comment: For future reference the spike trap worked marvelously.  Amazing how being poked repeatedly with a `Mahogany Spear` can make you want to get up and move.

Answer (score 4):

At this point, I believe the only medical attention McWounded can afford to seek is euthanasia, dwarf-style. Kill him with magma.